# Example of a set which contain only one interior point??? In real functions.

Tags: real-analysis

I know what is interior point but im unable to think of an example who has only one interior point??? 
Im also confused wether it possible or not to find sets who have finte number of interior point.

Comment: Is your set to be thought of as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$? If so, then the interior points of your set form an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and there are no finite non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Let $X$ be a one-point space. Then as a subset of itself, $X$ has one interior  point.

Comment: @KennyWong Unless $n=0$ :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Fair enough. :) Hopefully the OP can clarify...

Comment: Hi GURMEET SINGH and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always.  It depends on your topology space.  If it's $\mathbb R^n$ with the euclidean metric then there can be no such set.

Let $a$ be an interior point of $A$.  Then there is an open neighborhood with some real radius $\epsilon$ so that if $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $d(a,x) < \epsilon$ then $x \in A$.

So if we let $x$ be such a point so that $d(a,x) < \epsilon$ (if your space is $\mathbb R^n$ there will always be such a point) and let $\gamma < \epsilon - d(a,x)$.  Then for any point $y$ so that $d(y,x) < \gamma$ then $d(y,a) \le d(y,x)+ d(a,x) < \gamma + d(a,x) < \epsilon$.  So $x$ is also an interior point of $A$ and $a$ is not the only one.

However if you topology space is *not* $\mathbb R^n$ and is any space in which it is possible for there the be *no* $x$ so that $d(a,x) < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ then, yes, $a$ *could* be a solitary interior point.

For example if $X = (-\infty, 1) \cup \{0\} \cup (1, \infty)$ and $A = \{0\}$ then $a = 0$ *is* an interior point and it is the only one.  The set of *all* points $x\in X$ so that $d(0,x) < \frac 12$ is the set $\{0\}\subset A$ so $a=0$ *is* an interior point of $A$(!)

Or if $X = \mathbb R$ with the discreet topology and $A = \{0\}$ then $a = 0$ is an interior point. and it is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the metric.

Assume that we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 1 $

In the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$ where $d$ is the usual metric,it is impossible to find a set whose interior has only one point.

However if you take $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$  where $d$ is the discrete metric then in that metric space the singletons are open.

So a set $\{a\}$,$a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has exactly one interior point in this metric space.